# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Cannot find property length for HibernateValidator using TypeSafe

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, querydsl, hibernate-validator

I am looking to developed `Spring MVC + spring data jpa + Hibernate Validator` integration example. In this project I am facing below issue. It looks to me that `messages_en.properties` file is not getting loaded correctly which is resulting in below failure.

**I know the similar type of question being already raised on stack-overflow, but none solution works for me.**

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Cannot find property length
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.messageinterpolation.el.RootResolver.getValue(RootResolver.java:64)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:67)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:71)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:160)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.messageinterpolation.InterpolationTerm.interpolateExpressionLanguageTerm(InterpolationTerm.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.messageinterpolation.InterpolationTerm.interpolate(InterpolationTerm.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.interpolateExpression(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:342)
    at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.interpolateMessage(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.interpolate(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:194)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocaleContextMessageInterpolator.interpolate(LocaleContextMessageInterpolator.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidationContext.interpolate(ValidationContext.java:362)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidationContext.createConstraintViolation(ValidationContext.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidationContext.createConstraintViolations(ValidationContext.java:232)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:291)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:525)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:429)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:381)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:184)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.validate(DataBinder.java:782)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.validateIfApplicable(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:164)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:111)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:78)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:129)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:775)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:965)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:867)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:841)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Person.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PERSON")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @SafeHtml(whitelistType=WhiteListType.NONE, message="{html.validation.firstName}")
    @Length(max=50,min=2,message="${length.validation.firstName}")
    @Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstname;

    @SafeHtml(whitelistType=WhiteListType.NONE, message="{html.validation.lastName}")
    @Length(max=50,min=2,message="${length.validation.lastName}")
    @Column(name="LAST_NAME")
    private String lastname;

    @SafeHtml(whitelistType=WhiteListType.NONE, message="{html.validation.country}")
    @Length(max=50,min=2,message="${length.validation.country}")
    @Column(name="COUNTRY")
    private String country;

    @SafeHtml(whitelistType = SafeHtml.WhiteListType.NONE, message = "{html.validation.emailId}")
    @Length(max = 20, message = "${length.validation.emailId}")
    @Pattern(regexp = "^(.+)@(.+)$")
    @Column(name="EMAIL_ID")
    private String emailId;
    // setters and getters
}
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="spring-data-jpa-krishna" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>com.journaldev.spring.model.Person</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

messages_en.properties

```
html.validation.firstName=Invalid First Name
length.validation.firstName=First Name should be 2 to 50 lenght in characters
html.validation.lastName=Invalid Last Name
length.validation.lastName=Last Name should be 2 to 50 lenght in characters
html.validation.country=Invalid Country Name
length.validation.country=Country Name should be 2 to 50 lenght in characters
html.validation.emailId=Invalid Email ID
length.validation.emailId=Email ID length should not be more than 11 characters
```

pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.1.9.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.7.4</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.7.5</org.slf4j-version>
        <hibernate.version>5.1.0.Final</hibernate.version>

        <validation-api.version>1.1.0.Final</validation-api.version>
        <hibernate-validator.version>5.1.1.Final</hibernate-validator.version>

        <jsoup-version>1.8.1</jsoup-version>
        <spring-data-jpa-version>1.9.2.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>${validation-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-validator.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Querydsl dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- LOG4J -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-data-jpa-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Needed for Hibernate Validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>${jsoup-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSP API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Servlet API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Junit Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.37</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- Project Build -->
    <build>
        <finalName>spring-mvc-jpa-hibernate</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Specifies the directory in which the query types are generated -->
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                            <!-- States that the APT code generator should look for JPA annotations -->
                            <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

PersonRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Integer>{
    Person findById(int id);
}
```

servlet-context.xml

```
<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.journaldev.spring.controller" />

    <!-- Load database.properties file -->
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties" />

    <!-- Enable JPA Reporitories -->
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.journaldev.spring.repository" />

    <!-- Enable Transactional Manner -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <!-- Necessary to get the entity manager injected into the factory bean -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />


    <!-- ====== MYSQL DataSource ====== -->
    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="${mysql.jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <beans:property name="url" value="${mysql.jdbc.url}" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="${mysql.jdbc.userName}" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="${mysql.jdbc.password}" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- ====== Hibernate JPA Vendor Adaptor ======= -->
    <beans:bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <beans:property name="showSql" value="true"/>
        <beans:property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
        <beans:property name="database" value="MYSQL"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <!-- Beans -->
    <beans:bean id="personService" class="com.journaldev.spring.service.PersonServiceImpl" />
    <beans:bean id="visitService" class="com.journaldev.spring.service.VisitServiceImpl" />


    <!-- ======== Entity Manager factory ======== -->
    <beans:bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <!-- Data Source -->
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>

        <!-- JPA Vendor Adaptor -->
        <beans:property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>

        <!-- spring based scanning for entity classes-->
        <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.journaldev.spring.*" />

        <beans:property name="jpaProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</beans:prop>  <!-- validate | update | create | create-drop -->
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</beans:prop>
                <!-- <beans:prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</beans:prop> --> 
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- ======== Transaction Manager ==== -->
    <beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </beans:bean>


    <!-- Localization of hibernate messages during validation!-->
    <beans:bean id="validationMessageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <beans:property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean name="validator"  class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="validationMessageSource">
           <beans:ref bean="validationMessageSource"/>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>


    <!-- This is for JSP -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never be using the `$` for placeholders. Simply use following code. This will resolved your errors:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PERSON")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @SafeHtml(whitelistType=WhiteListType.NONE, message="{html.validation.firstName}")
    @Length(max=50,min=2,message="{length.validation.firstName}")
    @Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstname;

    @SafeHtml(whitelistType=WhiteListType.NONE, message="{html.validation.lastName}")
    @Length(max=50,min=2,message="{length.validation.lastName}")
    @Column(name="LAST_NAME")
    private String lastname;

    @SafeHtml(whitelistType=WhiteListType.NONE, message="{html.validation.country}")
    @Length(max=50,min=2,message="{length.validation.country}")
    @Column(name="COUNTRY")
    private String country;

    @SafeHtml(whitelistType = SafeHtml.WhiteListType.NONE, message = "{html.validation.emailId}")
    @Length(max = 20, message = "{length.validation.emailId}")
    @Pattern(regexp = "^(.+)@(.+)$")
    @Column(name="EMAIL_ID")
    private String emailId;
    // setters and getters
}
```